# How to force IntelliJ to always search in "Whole Project"

Tags: search, intellij-idea

I like to use the **Find in Path** function <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+F</kbd>, that searches for text strings in several files.

One thing I often run into though, is that I search for something that I know exists in at least one file, I get zero results or I find just some of the files that contain the search term.

Then I realise that the Scope setting in the **Find Dialog** box has been set to Module or Directory for some reason rather that "Whole project" which is what I almost always want.

What fools me here is that this only seems to happen occasionally - often I'll have the scope set to **Whole project** like I want to, but sometimes it will be something else.

How does IntelliJ decide which scope to use?

Also, is there some setting that can be used to force IntelliJ to always select "Whole project" as the default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just collapse the project tab before: <kbd>Command + 1</kbd> or <kbd>Alt + 1</kbd>

The default selection depends on the context which launched the search. If you have the project tab open with a folder/file selected it will search in that folder or the parent of that file.

To search by default just close that panel (this will make the context be the whole project) and press the search shortcut and it will be scope properly.

Comment: Hm ok thanks. Closing the project tab is a bit awkward, but it seems that clicking in the source code will also cause scope to be set to whole project.

Comment: True. The truth is that you rarely need the project tab open since you can quickly navigate to a class, method, file if you have a project with decently named classes. So i prefer to keep collapsed and only open it when i need to :).

Comment: the problem is that if I do a find in path and then look at results and do another one immediately, it defaults to the directory where the first search result was for the previous search.  It is very annoying.

Answer (score 5):

Not really a solution, but how to avoid using the mouse for this:

When the dialog is open, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> before pressing enter. This will cause the scope to be set to *Whole project*.

Comment: Actually that's alt p for me - maybe because I haven't upgraded to the latest IntelliJ version. Anyway, this is a good tip, I hadn't noticed that there were classic keyboard shortcuts like that in this dialog, with underlined characters in options. Now I can use whole words and regexp superfast too. :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Figured out that you can select/focus any UI element (with label) by pressing the character underlined in the label while Alt / Option pressed. e.g, Option + P for Whole Project, M for Module, D for Directory etc.